# using boost::asio::local with MinGW

Tags: c++, boost, mingw, boost-asio, local

Is it possible use `boost::asio::local` with MinGw ? according to [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/posix/local.html) link Unix local sockets is not supported in windows.

EDIT: I am building an already exist code that has used `asio::local` classes. Building under MinGw failed. Is there any workaround to fix it ? compiler says `local` does not a member of `asio`. I feel there is a trick to fix it. please help. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MinGW will not support a POSIX application.  Instead, consider using [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).

The [`boost::asio::local`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/posix/local.html) objects utilize POSIX features and [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) explicitly states that it will not provide a POSIX runtime environment:

> **MinGW**, being Minimalist, **does not, and never will, attempt to provide a POSIX runtime environment for POSIX application deployment on MS-Windows**. If you want POSIX application deployment on this platform, please consider Cygwin instead.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of investigation, I've found out there is no way to use `asio::local` in windows. It is unportable.